# PyAudio on Ubuntu list devices only if run with sudo

Tags: python, pyaudio

Using Ubuntu 20, python3.10...I have a simple script to list devices:

```
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print('\navailable devices:')
for i in range(pa.get_device_count()):
    dev = pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    name = dev['name'].encode('utf-8')
    print(i, name, dev['maxInputChannels'], dev['maxOutputChannels'])

print('\ndefault input & output device:')
print(pa.get_default_input_device_info())
print(pa.get_default_output_device_info())
```

when I run it with sudo it list the devices:

```
test@test-user:~/google-tests$ sudo python3.10 list-devices.py
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline

available devices:
0 b'Intel 82801AA-ICH: - (hw:0,0)' 2 2
1 b'Intel 82801AA-ICH: MIC ADC (hw:0,1)' 2 0
2 b'sysdefault' 128 128
3 b'front' 0 2
4 b'default' 128 128
5 b'dmix' 0 2

default input & output device:
{'index': 4, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'default', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 128, 'maxOutputChannels': 128, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0}
{'index': 4, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'default', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 128, 'maxOutputChannels': 128, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0}
```

but when I run it without sudo it does not find any devices:

```
available devices:

default input & output device:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test-user/google-tests/list-devices.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(pa.get_default_input_device_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyAudio-0.2.13-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 812, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

What could be causing this?